# Can I launch an ansible playbook from a cygwin terminal on windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, flask, ansible

I created a Flask Web App that uses an html form button to launch a Python script via a subproces call.  I want that Python script to launch cygwin and pass a shell script that launches an ansible playbook.  But the playbook is not running.  The screen just flickers and nothing is happening.

The flask web app works when testing on its own.  on its own it can write to a text file

Answer (score 0):

I think more information would be helpfull but basicly you can invoke ansible by any tool who can send commands to machine. Maybe the subprocess is the problem you should consider to use the call with: nohup and pipe all outputs to:  /dev/null 2>&1